# .NET Core build works on one machine, not the other

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, .net-core, csproj

I have a .NET Core project I'm working on, but I'm having issues building it on one of my machines and I can't for the life of me figure out what is causing the issue.

On my Win10 Anniversary x64 tablet, if I open a command line in the project folder and run `dotnet build`, the project builds successfully and I get an output file in the `bin` folder as expected.

On my Win10 10240 x64 desktop, when I run the same command in the same folder (same Git repository and HEAD even), I get an error for every `.cs` file in the project:

`CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'C:\[source file]' could not be found.`

In the errors, `[source file]` is always the relative path of the file from the `.csproj` file. For example, for `<project dir>\Dom\IChildNode.cs`, the error is:

`CSC : error CS2001: Source file 'C:\Dom\IChildNode.cs' could not be found.`

I can't figure out where there would be a difference in machine configuration that would cause my desktop to incorrectly look in the drive root for relative project file paths whereas my tablet correctly searches in the project directory. I am using the same version of .NET Core CLI tools (1.0.4) and the same MSBuild version.

Comment: are you running the command in the path where project.json could be found on your desktop?

Comment: I'm not using `project.json` files anymore...I just converted this project to use the new VS2017 `.csproj` format for .NET Core. I'm running the command in the same folder on both machines, and the project file only exists in that location on each machine.

On my desktop, the project is in `C:\Users\<me>\Projects\<project>` and on my tablet, it is in `C:\Users\<me>\Documents\Development\<project>`

Comment: What is the output of `dotnet --version` on both machines?

Comment: @DavidG `1.0.4` on both.

If I run just `dotnet`, I get the same output on both machines as well:

`Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 1.1.0
  Build    : 928f77c4bc3f49d892459992fb6e1d5542cb5e86`

Comment: It's not a permission thing then perhaps? Maybe try to recreate the git repo from fresh.

Comment: Already tried that...I get this problem on multiple repos that all build fine on my tablet. I have tried running `powershell` as administrator when building, but it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: How about a fresh project? `dotnet new console` and then `dotnet build`?

Comment: (not forgetting `dotnet restore` in the middle of course!)

Comment: @DavidG here's the result: http://i.imgur.com/skLyvWj.png

I've already tried re-installing/repairing the .NET Core SDK to no avail.

Comment: Hmm very strange. Check for a `global.json` file in the hierarchy somewhere, it's possible that is interfering. Also just from a plain command prompt (i.e. not `powershell`)

Comment: Another thing to try is build with full detailed diagnostic output turned on `dotnet build -v diag`

Comment: can you share your csproj file? is there a `Directory.Build.props` / `.targets` file in the directory hierarchy?

Comment: The `.csproj` file is here: https://github.com/briman0094/AngleSharp/blob/csproj/src/AngleSharp/AngleSharp.Core.csproj

(which is my fork of AngleSharp)

If you clone the `csproj` branch, you should be able to compile the project with `build.ps1` or by running `dotnet build` in `src/AngleSharp`, whereas I cannot do either on my desktop.